# How to open a created file from java program after button click in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have created a program in netbeans where button click creates a pdf file in home directory but what codes I have to add to open it after button click.

```
package demopdf;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author sunil
 */

public class DemoPdfCreate extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static final String RESULT="Report.pdf";



/**
 * Creates new form DemoPdfCreate
 */
public DemoPdfCreate() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated 
Code">                          

private void initComponents() {

    jButton_pdf = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField_txt = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton_pdf.setText("Save To Pdf");
    jButton_pdf.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton_pdfActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout
(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup
(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                    .addComponent(jTextField_txt, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 266, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                    .addComponent(jButton_pdf, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(81, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup
(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 
layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTextField_txt, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap
(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton_pdf, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37,   
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(64, 64, 64))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton_pdfActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Document doc =new Document();
try {
  try {  
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DemoPdfCreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
ex);
}
    doc.open();

    doc.add(new Paragraph(jTextField_txt.getText()));

     doc.close();

} catch (DocumentException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DemoPdfCreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
ex);
}



}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting 
code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the 
default look and feel.
     * For details see 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : 
javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DemoPdfCreate.class.getName
()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DemoPdfCreate.class.getName
()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DemoPdfCreate.class.getName
()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DemoPdfCreate.class.getName
()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new DemoPdfCreate().setVisible(true);
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton_pdf;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_txt;
// End of variables declaration                   


}
```

I have created above program and from that using itextpdf.jar I can able to create the pdf file in my frograms directory which iwant to open when it is created under same button click

Comment: I don't want to use openfiledialog, just like Process.Start and file path use in vb. what should be the codes to use in java to open file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try `Desktop.open(File)`, which:

Launches the associated application to open the file.

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // no application registered for PDFs
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep.  This is the easiest way to achieve it.

Comment: This has help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this in your actionperfomrmed-method: `File yourSavedFile = new File("path to your saved file")`. After that you can read from that file and display it.

Comment: OP asked about opening the file as a regular file based on applications installed in OS, not in reading mode of a text file.

Comment: It was very unclear what he really meant. I am sorry if i missunderstood it.

Comment: how shall I add my programs code in question it is showing only code added and I am unable to edit and add codes of my program

Comment: I have added codes which may clear your idea. I want to open created file through the same button.